# How to sync my Android application with a website?

Tags: android, sqlite, synchronization

Here I launched the first version of my [flash card application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.co.discoverit.my_FlashCards)

I am working on Flash Card application. Here I used a sqlite database to store my cards and data.

Now I want to synchronize my database with website database.

So how would I do this for my application? Also, tell me the possible ways to do this on both device side and website side.

Comment: You need to communicate with website DB using web services which will provide you details or data of the tables and you need to parse from WS then store in your sqlite database.

Comment: yes,i want to allow user to create the cards of application on website and sync with mobile device application database??

Comment: @Pranav I would like to know how did you do it or if there is any material to help me understand the process.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend taking a look at [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/).  It is a great solution and best part is that it is free for under a certain amount of usage.

Comment: I have my own Url or we can say web site where i can allow user to create cards but i need to know how to sync my websites DB with my android application DB which is on user device??

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question anymore, but I would think you need some kind of event based servlet to get request and send responses for the database.

Comment: take a look at this article maybe it can help you
http://bradabrams.com/2011/05/google-io-session-overview-android-app-engine-a-developers-dream-combination/

Answer (score 1):

make a webservice which will give you necessary fields of tables from database in xml or json formate. You need to parse the xml response you got and create a database in your mobile application store values in DB which you have parsed.

http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parseread-xml-data-into-android-listview/

From this link you will get idea about what you will need from WS and how to parse the WS responses.

Answer (score 1):

Wonder if you have considered using a Sync Framework to manage the synchronization. If that interests you can take a look at the open source project, OpenMobster's Sync service. You can do the following sync operations

- two-way
- one-way client
- one-way device
- bootup

Besides that, all modifications are automatically tracked and synced with the Cloud. You can have your app offline when network connection is down. It will track any changes and automatically in the background synchronize it with the cloud when the connection returns. It also provides synchronization like iCloud across multiple devices

On the Cloud/website side, there is a Java Channel Framework to expose your data to the Sync Engine. You write a simple CRUD based Sync Channel and all your data will be kept in sync with the data on the device.

Here is a link to the open source project: http://openmobster.googlecode.com

Here is some sample code to see how these come together: http://openmobster.googlecode.com/svn/samples/offlineapp.zip

Full Disclosure: I am the Chief Engineer of the OpenMobster project